# Exclude function types from an object type

Tags: typescript

In the following excerpt of code:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  bestFriend: User;
  getInfo: () => any;
}

type MyCustomType = {
  [key in keyof User]: User[key]
};
```

<sup>[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRyIcAthAFzLphSgDmA3AccnA1SQK5kBG0FoWIDaAMXoQQAE2oZBrYpzABJEDAD21ABQBKZAF4AfOxABPAgF8CBMGYAOKALJmAwt1oayAFQcoDOIpEANoA1hBmyKDI4WYaMGiYUAC6cklhEclWQgQA9LnIABIaAG5YpVhgABYoAAYu7p4+frXIdo4AdMgAmhrcAOQANoM0ECjVcGBRU1Vw6G01yABEymqaS8gw3CAIYMAaIG1+HXkFKvPV0ChwyADucJFgGsgQAB4Ig9zS18NHjhezKZwKDXTbbXb7EAAfiAA)</sup>

Is there a way to remove only the function types of that interface? I've created the `MyCustomType` type, but I did not find a way to remove the function types, such as `getInfo`.

How can I allow only non-functions types in that `MyCustomType` type?

P.S.: Types such as `User` should not be filtered out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is one of the listed examples of the [Distributive Conditional
Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)
examples on the "Advanced Types" page of the Typescript handbook.

> Conditional types are particularly useful when combined with mapped types:
>
> ```js
> type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T];
> type FunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, FunctionPropertyNames<T>>;
>
> type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
> type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;
>
> interface Part {
>     id: number;
>     name: string;
>     subparts: Part[];
>     updatePart(newName: string): void;
> }
>
> type T40 = FunctionPropertyNames<Part>;  // "updatePart"
> type T41 = NonFunctionPropertyNames<Part>;  // "id" | "name" | "subparts"
> type T42 = FunctionProperties<Part>;  // { updatePart(newName: string): void }
> type T43 = NonFunctionProperties<Part>;  // { id: number, name: string, subparts: Part[] }
> ```

[A quick search of the Typescript Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?q=NonFunctionProperties&unscoped_q=NonFunctionProperties) reveals that this type is not currently a built-in utility type (unlike the undocumented types [`Parameters<T>` and `ConstructorParameters<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1456-L1464)), so you'll have to define the `NonFunctionProperties` equivalent yourself.

Comment: is there any way to do it recursive?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simplified version of Jeff's comprehensive answer and a 
[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRyIcAthAFzLphSgDmA3AccnA1SQK5kBG0FoWIDaAMXoQQAE2oZBrYpzABJEDAD21ABQBKZAF4AfOxABPAgF8CBMGYAOKMdxAIwwDSAAKUDY6h2AHLkEOgAPAAqJgY4yIpEANoA0sigyADWEGYaMMgRALrUEcn5yBAAHpAy6MjOru6eyAD8yCnUIBAAblhWCZnZuQVCtg4oALJmAMLctBpkEaOGyADyZMBgYfJQADS1Lm4e3r7+QSHhW0ZGw-gA9DfIABIa3VDIz1hgABYoAAYT07N5qMfsg7I4AHTIACaGm4AHIADYImgQFBfOBgVKYz5wGpfFAAImUak0BOQMH2DRAoNG4IId2QKjx3ygKDgyAA7nAzKCNGVyggEdxpGykTTHMyMexWexyZTDk0gA).

```js
interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    bestFriend: User;
    getInfo: () => any
}

// Do not worry too much about understanding this 
// until you're ready for advanced TypeScript.
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = { 
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never 
}[keyof T];

type MyCustomType = Omit<User, FunctionPropertyNames<User>>;
```

**Result:**

[image]